Does Dagger2 support Custom InjectionResolvers similar to org.glassfish.hk2.api. InjectionResolver
My current android project employs Dagger/Hilt for dependency injection. I have a requirement for custom resolution of injected dependencies in part of this project. having researched dagger/hilt i cannot find any mention of anything that suits my use case. I did find org.glassfish.hk2.api. InjectionResolver in glassfish api that seems to be the perfect solution however neither dagger or hilt appear to provide any similar feature.
is there no approach i can take to satisfy my use case for custom resolution of dependecies?
the closest i can get is using @Named and or @Qualified annotations however this feels quiet clumsy approach compared to developing a custom InjectionResolver
